# Does $\text{diam}(A)=\inf\{\rho>0;A\subset B[a,\rho/2],\forall a\in M\}$ hold?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Some days ago I was of studying metric spaces and a few drawings later I've come to a "conjecture"

> Let $A$ be subset of the metric space $(M,d)$ then $\text{diam}(A)=\inf\{\rho>0;A\subset B[a,\rho/2],\forall a\in M\}$

As far as I know it can be **false** in general, it depends on the space that we are working on. By some drawings, it may make sense in vector spaces, then I am supposing we are on these ones.

It's clear that if $A\subset B[x,r/2]$ then $\text{diam}(A)\leq r$, then my first ideia was a construction of some balls with decrescent sequence of radius and each one has the set $A$ contained in it. For that idea work is needed to change the center of each ball, then I've start to consider the maximum distance from some point $a_1$ to another point in $A$, let $b_1$ be that point and $d(a_1,b_1)=r_1$. Done this we have that $A\subset B_1=B[a_1,r_1]$. Let $a_2$ be the midpoint of the segment $a_1b_1$ and repeat this process over and over. We would have $$A\subset B_n\subset B_{n-1}\subset\cdots\subset B_3\subset B_2\subset B_1$$ 
with $r_n\to \text{diam}(A)$. But this construction has the problem that maybe $b_1$ no exists at all, this can be seen if we take some open interval $(a,b)$ on the real line or some other set that is not compact.

Despite the intuition, I have no proof or counter example for that, can you give me some lead ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the discrete metric. Let $A=\{x,y\}$ with $x \neq y$. If $A \subset B [a, \rho /2]$ and $\rho < 2$ then $d(x,a) <1$ and $d(y,a) <1$. Hence $x=a$ and $y=a$, a contradiction. Hence the infimum in your equation is at least $2$. But the diameter of $A$ is $1$.